# AS400 with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ibm-midrange

I am trying to access our AS400 database with Ruby on Rails, using the "dbi" gem and the "dbd-odbc" gem.

I have found this code to build off of. When I pass in the server address...
It seems that the original code uses an DSN, but I wanted to pass in the IP, database name, and library in the code to prevent any DSN being needed.

```
require 'dbi'
dbh = DBI.connect('DBI:ODBC:SYSTEM=<ip_address>;DBQ=<db_name>;DFTPKGLIB=<library_name>;LANGUAGEID=ENU', 'UID=<user_name>', 'PWD=<password>')
sth = dbh.prepare('select count(*) from my_table')
sth.execute

# Print out each row
while row=sth.fetch do
  p row
end

sth.finish
dbh.disconnect
```

it gives me an error of...

```
DBI::InterfaceError: Unable to load driver 'ODBC'
```

what would be the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me - also, just put your authentication portion inside of the first argument to the DBI.connect function:

First install the gems: dbi, dbd-odbc, ruby-odbc.  I was getting the same error without the ruby-odbc gem

Then:

```
require 'odbc'

require 'dbi'

dbh = DBI.connect('DBI:ODBC:SYSTEM=MYAS400;DBQ=TABLE_NAME;DFTPKGLIB=SCHEMA_NAME;DRIVER=Client Access ODBC Driver (32-bit);LANGUAGEID=ENU;USERID=SUPERADMIN;PWD=SUPERSECURE')
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know exactly how that works in Ruby, but in the connection string I don't see where you mention the driver your trying to use to connect.

Seems like this line:

```
dbh = DBI.connect('DBI:ODBC:SYSTEM=<ip_address>;DBQ=<db_name>;DFTPKGLIB=<library_name>;LANGUAGEID=ENU', 'UID=<user_name>', 'PWD=<password>')
```

needs to be something like this to indicate the driver ODBC should use to connect:

```
dbh = DBI.connect('DBI:ODBC:Driver=iSeries Access ODBC Driver;SYSTEM=<ip_address>;DBQ=<db_name>;DFTPKGLIB=<library_name>;LANGUAGEID=ENU', 'UID=<user_name>', 'PWD=<password>')
```

Comment: I was under the impression that with the dbi gem and the did-odbc gem there was no need to have a DSN installed on the server. I am currently in development and I'm not wanting to make it so I would have to rely on the production server to install the DSN. Am I correct in thinking that the DSN would not be needed if the dbi and the did-odbc gems had the driver?

Comment: The DSN is basically just all the stuff in the connection string with a name applied.  You would have to make sure the server had the driver installed though.